# pythonで配列の1つ目と2つ目の要素を条件に3つ目の要素を決定する。

Tags: python, python3

2次元リストがあり、1つ目の要素と2つ目の要素を条件に3つ目に入れる要素を決定したいです。

```
li=np.array([-1,-2]
            [ 1,-2]
            [-1, 2]
            [ 1, 2]
             )
```

具体的には
(1つ目の要素 < 0) and (2つ目の要素 < 0) なら3つ目に1を
(1つ目の要素 > 0) and (2つ目の要素 < 0) なら3つ目に2を
(1つ目の要素 < 0) and (2つ目の要素 > 0) なら3つ目に3を
(1つ目の要素 > 0) and (2つ目の要素 > 0) なら3つ目に4を
追加し、

```
result=[[-1,-2, 1]
        [ 1,-2, 2]
        [-1, 2, 3]
        [ 1, 2, 4]]
```

となるようなものです。

内包表現やシーケンス操作(filterやmap、where)を用いる方法で行いたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

これでどうでしょう

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> li = np.array([[-1, -2],
...                [ 1, -2],
...                [-1,  2],
...                [ 1,  2]])
>>> n = li.shape[0]
>>> li2 = np.hstack([li, np.zeros((n,1))])
>>> li2
array([[-1., -2.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  0.],
       [-1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.]])
>>> li2[np.where((li2[:,0]<0) & (li2[:,1]<0)),2] = 1
>>> li2[np.where((li2[:,0]>0) & (li2[:,1]<0)),2] = 2
>>> li2[np.where((li2[:,0]<0) & (li2[:,1]>0)),2] = 3
>>> li2[np.where((li2[:,0]>0) & (li2[:,1]>0)),2] = 4
>>> li2
array([[-1., -2.,  1.],
       [ 1., -2.,  2.],
       [-1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  4.]])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。whereの複数条件の書き方がわからなかったので、勉強になります。

Answer (score 1):

一応かけましたが、もっと良い方法があるような気がします。
あと読みにくいので自分は素直に`for`で書かれたものの方が好きです。

```
li = [[-1,-2],
      [ 1,-2],
      [-1, 2],
      [ 1, 2]]

[ i + [(1 if i[0]>0 else 0)+(2 if i[1]>0 else 0)+1] for i in li ]
```

出力

```
[[-1, -2, 1], [1, -2, 2], [-1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

---

**追記**
少し短くできたので追記。

```
[ i + [int(i[0]>0) + int(i[1]>0)*2 + 1] for i in li ]
```

あと`numpy`を使うと以下のようにもかけます。
もしかすると速いかもしれませんが、すごく読みにくいです。
もっと良い方法知っている方がいましたら、お願いします。

```
import numpy as np
ni = np.array(li)

np.hstack(( ni, np.sum((ni>0)*[1,2],1)[None].T+1 ))   # 方法1
np.vstack(( ni.T, np.sum((ni.T>0)*[[1],[2]],0)+1 )).T # 方法2
```

Comment: booleanを整数として使うならintは不要で [ i + [(i[0]>0) + (i[1]>0)*2 + 1] for i in li ] まで短くなりますが、もとのifを使った式の方がよいと感じました

Comment: ありがとうございます。速度を求めるようなプログラムなので助かります。